# Windows 7 update changed user profile path to temp/moved old files

Tags: windows-7, windows, updates, user-profiles

My aunt has an old HP G7 laptop. She was in word and saved stuff to her desktop and documents. She shut the computer off and it must have updated windows. When she restarted, her files were gone from desktop and documents.

I looked at the computer and there is a temp hp user under C:\Users. Her user profile is now set to that folder from the update. Her old files are under C:\Users\Monique (her old user profile and current username.) Is there any way to change the path of the user profile to get her files back to normal? They are still there but she doesn't want to go to that path every time to find her stuff.

Idk what caused the user profile to change to a new temp path in the update, but something went wrong. Her wallpaper also changed (not a big deal though).

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: When she logs in does she see both the accounts? Or does it load a temporary profile? Of course we can access the old user folder by changing permissions (by taking ownership and restore the files to similar places in the new user) but if Windows is loading a temp profile it has to be fixed. https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/14039/windows-7-fix-corrupted-user-profile lists a way to create a profile and copy the files.

Comment: It logs in as her in as her normal user account like always. I assume it's logging in as a different profile though.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new user account to fix the corrupted user profile. I think following link could help you solve the problem.

Fix a corrupted user profile in Windows 7:https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/14039/windows-7-fix-corrupted-user-profile